# CSS text justification won't center

Tags: html, css

I've got a bit of a daft problem here.  I'm trying to centre justify a paragraph so it looks like this:

[image]

Instead...it looks like this:

[image]

I want a paragraph which is totally straight. 
 This applies to < h2 > paragraph < /h2 >

I've tried:

```
text-align: justify;
```

and

```
text-align: center;
```

This is the css for slide 2

```
/*slide 2 */
#slide-2 .bcg {
position: relative;
background-color: #1C1C1C;
padding:200px;
}

slide-2 .hsContent {
        position: relative;
}

slide-2 .hscontainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 80%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position:relative;
}
#slide-2 h1 {
               /*  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);*/
                margin-top:0;
                 padding:20px;
                color: #d2d2d2;
                font-size: 30px;
                line-height: 20px;
                 position: relative;
               text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#slide-2 h2 {
                 bottom: 10px;
                 color: #696d6d;
                 font-size: 16px;
                 line-height: 150%;
                 position: absolute;
                 line-spacing: 1px;
                 text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no over-riding rule? Can you please create a fiddle demo?

Comment: try using !important.

Comment: Are you sure all that block of text is an h2 tag? Text-align justify is correct and should work, please post your html as well if not

Comment: Definitely using a h2 tag.

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ocgjLaxx/). I would have to assume something in your code is overriding your definitions. Check the CSS in the web inspector.

Comment: It works now...but only when I remove <br> between lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can try CSS3 hyphens with attributes none | manuel | auto

The hyphens property controls hyphenation of text in block level elements. You can prevent hyphenation from happening at all, allow it, or only allow it when certain characters are present.

```
.textclass{ 
hyphens: auto; 
text-align: justify
}
```

If you don't want to use the code above you can try to write your break lines a little bit differently.

It can appear that your tags are overriding something.

Try:

```
<br />
<br></br> 
</br>
```

any of these should do the trick.